# How to check which cell is clicked in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

In the first column of my datagridview, I have checkboxes and I want to fire an event each time the status of the checkbox is changed. I thought of using the cellcontentclick event, casting the sender object to datagridviewcell and checking by its column index. But I found out that the sender object is a datagridview object. So, how to perform the desired operation?

Comment: Is this Winforms, Wpf or Asp.net

Comment: how did you bind the data to your `DataGridView`? `bindingSource`, `DataTable` or Unbound data?

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods

One Method is : 
You can take a `hidden field` or `viewstate` on page in which you can store row id when click occured by javascript and then in code behind get that hiddenfield value.

Other one :  
You can use `CommandName`  &  `CommandArgument`  and in code behind use `datagridview_ItemCommand`

Answer (score 1):

To handle `CheckBoxCell` value changed you have to use this event `CellValueChanged`. Sender in events will always be the control that raised the event. To have more information about what happend you need to take a look into `EventArgs`.

Back to handling `CheckBoxCell` do this:

```
private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
     var check = dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value as bool?;

     if (check.HasValue)
     {
         if (check) 
         {
             //checked
         }
         else
         {
             //unchecked
         }
     }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgvStandingOrder_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dgvStandingOrder.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "IsSelected" && dgvStandingOrder.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
                {
                    bool isChecked = (bool)dgvStandingOrder[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue;
                    if (isChecked == false)
                    {
                        dgvStandingOrder.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Status"].Value = "";
                    }
                    dgvStandingOrder.EndEdit();
                }
            }

            private void dgvStandingOrder_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {

                dgvStandingOrder.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }

            private void dgvStandingOrder_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (dgvStandingOrder.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
                {
                    dgvStandingOrder.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                }   
            }
```